# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: cafe

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I've coming up to a strange error when I run the starter files of a python udemy course, at first, here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

##Connect to Database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///cafes.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


##Cafe TABLE Configuration
class Cafe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    map_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    seats = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    has_toilet = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    has_wifi = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    has_sockets = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    can_take_calls = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    coffee_price = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
    

## HTTP GET - Read Record
@app.route("/random")
def get_random_cafe():
    cafes = db.session.query(Cafe).all()
    random_cafe = random.choice(cafes)
    return jsonify(cafe={
        #Omit the id from the response
        # "id": random_cafe.id,
        "name": random_cafe.name,
        "map_url": random_cafe.map_url,
        "img_url": random_cafe.img_url,
        "location": random_cafe.location,
        
        #Put some properties in a sub-category
        "amenities": {
          "seats": random_cafe.seats,
          "has_toilet": random_cafe.has_toilet,
          "has_wifi": random_cafe.has_wifi,
          "has_sockets": random_cafe.has_sockets,
          "can_take_calls": random_cafe.can_take_calls,
          "coffee_price": random_cafe.coffee_price,
        }
    })

## HTTP POST - Create Record

## HTTP PUT/PATCH - Update Record

## HTTP DELETE - Delete Record


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I direct to "/random" I get this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: cafe` But this table exists, it's right in my directory filled with data, or am I missing anything, I really don't understand what to do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*Edited after further doc reading

This is a guess, but the section on the SQLite configuration says that the database URI path has to be an absolute path.

```py
#Unix/Mac (note the four leading slashes)
sqlite:////absolute/path/to/foo.db
#Windows (note 3 leading forward slashes and backslash escapes)
sqlite:///C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\foo.db
#Windows (alternative using raw string)
r'sqlite:///C:\absolute\path\to\foo.db'
```

It might be worth checking that you are connecting to the database file you think you are. I am wondering if you have two, one sitting on the root of your file system and the one you created the table in.

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#connection-uri-format